# Javascript Form Dropdown That changes second Dropdown option

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu

First and foremost, I know this must be simple but I am just not seeing how to do what I need to do. 
What I need is a JS form dropdown that lists an array of locations. In which a second dropdown will then show a selected group of 'course dates'. Because all of the locations have varying dates of service, this second dropdown will need to change upon the first initial selection.

```
<select class="form-control" id="campus" name="campus" required="" title="Campus">
            <option value="AIMNAT" style="alignment-adjust:middle;" selected="selected">Select Your Nearest Location</option>
            <option value="AMA">Atlanta, GA</option>
            <option value="AMD">Dallas, TX</option>
            <option value="AMH">Houston, TX</option>
            <option value="AMI">Indianapolis, IN</option>
            <option value="AMK">Kansas City, MO</option>
            <option value="AIML">Las Vegas, NV</option>
            <option value="AMO">Orlando, FL</option>
            <option value="AMP">Philadelphia, PA</option>
            <option value="AMS">San Francisco, CA</option>
            <option value="AMN">Virginia Beach, VA</option>
            <option value="AMM">Washington, DC</option>

            </select>
```

I have my location form selection above, I am just not sure how to go about adding the right course schedules to each location as above. The second dropdown will need to state, "Choose your schedule" and then have a populated list of dates that are pertainable to the campus the user selected. As an example for Atlanta, I would need August 19-20th, September 16-17th, and October 14-15th. And for Dallas I would need August 5-6th & 12-13th, September 9-10 & 16-17, October 14-15 & 21-22, and November 11-12 & 18-19.

Thank you so much for your knowledge, insight, and assistance.

Comment: please post what you already have tried.

Comment: How would I link this into HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, here's what I would have done:

```
var locations = {
    "AMA" : {
        "August 19-20",
        "September 19-20",
        "January 19-20"
    },
    "AMH" : {
        "August 19-20",
        "September 19-20",
        "January 19-20"
    },
    "AIML" : {
        "August 19-20",
        "September 19-20",
        "January 19-20"
    }
};

// when user selects a location
$('.locations-select').on('change', function() {
    // get selected option
    var location = $('.locations-select option:selected');

    // clear the pervious options for dates
    $('.dates-select').empty();

    // popluate dates
    $.each(locations[locaiton], function(idx, el) {
        $('.dates-select').append('<option value="' + idx + '">' + el + "</option>");
    })
})
```

And a bit of explanation:

1. You need to know which timings map to which locations. If this map
   is not static (I just did it for simplicity), you might need to do
   an AJAX call to the server to fetch the list by location
2. When location is selected, you clear the dates select and populate
   it with valid dates options.

Comment: Oh! I think this will work!! Now, when making the dropdown in HTML how might I go about linking it to this script?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data=[
{"ID":"AMA", "ParentID":null, "value":"Atlanta, GA"},{"ID":"date", "ParentID":"AMA", "value":"August 19-20th"},
{"ID":"date", "ParentID":"AMA", "value":"September 16-17th"},{"ID":"date", "ParentID":"AMA", "value":"October 14-15th"},
{"ID":"AMD", "ParentID":null, "value":"Dallas, TX"},{"ID":"date", "ParentID":"AMD", "value":"August 5-6th"},
{"ID":"date", "ParentID":"AMD", "value":"August 12-13th"},{"ID":"date", "ParentID":"AMD", "value":"September 9-10 "},
];
```

keep all your data in json format like above.

Now when in the **first dropdown** *Atlanta* will be selected, search it in the json and get its **ID** value. Now again search whose **parentID** is same as *Atlanta's ID*. Get their value and append in second dropdown. You just need a couple of search operations in the json. Hope it helps you.

Comment: This looks great! could you show me how to link to the json api and fit these variables into my form dropdown in HTML??

Comment: In your html page you can write this json and javascript inside `<script></script>` and you can access the json data in **for loop** . like `data[i].ParentID , data[i].ID or data[i].value`